# Xamarin Android: F# icon not being picked up by Resources

Tags: f#, xamarin.android

Create an F# Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio 10.

The template contains a set of `mipmap` folders, to which you can add your own icons.

If I add the icon `my_icon.png` to each of the mipmap folders, then they should be picked up as a drawable resource: i.e. I should be able to use

```
type MyResources = MyProject.Resource
```

and then the compiler should pick up

```
let myIcon = MyResources.Drawable.my_icon
```

But it isn't.

Is this a bug? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is laughably obvious.

The resource lives in `MyResources.Mipmap`:

```
let myIcon = MyResources.Mipmap.my_icon
```